# Angular - Observable filter is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, rxjs, observable

In my database I have users which all need to complete homework sessions. Each homework session has a *unique id*, *unique name*, *date* and other *metadata*.

When retrieved from the database, all the homework of a user is stored into a `private userHomework: Observable<any>`. I then wish to search for a specific homework by name which the user types.

I use the following function:

```
this.userHomework = this.userHomework.map(allHomework => 
    allHomework.filter(homeworkSession =>
 homeworkSession.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.userInput.toLowerCase())));
```

However, when executed I get the following error: `allHomework.filter is not a function`.

I have tried importing the filter in two different ways:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

and

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

When using the second import, I also get the following warning:

```
[ts] 'filter' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Could anyone explain where my mistake is and how can I successfully filter my Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allHomework` in your case is not `Observable` but `any` (as you declared) emitted by `userHomework` observable. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function may be applied to arrays, so try this:

- make sure `allHomework` is an array
- declare it: `private userHomework: Observable<any>[]`
- remove Observable's `filter` imports

Comment: Worked as a charm.